# Need help computing the double integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(x + y)}{x + y} \mathop{dy} \mathop{dx}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, substitution

Need help computing the double integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(x + y)}{x + y} \mathop{dy} \mathop{dx}.$

I know that $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(u) \mathop{du}$ equals $1$. The entire integral should come out to be $1$.

I am new to multivariable calculus and would appreciate some help.

Making the substitution $u = x + y$ and $v = y$, we get $\mathop{du} = \mathop{dx} + \mathop{dy}$ and $\mathop{dv} = \mathop{dy}$. So,

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(u)}{u} \mathop{dy} \mathop{dx}$$

I don't know what to change the $dy$ and $dx$ to since $du$ has both $dx$ and $dy$ in it. Also, for the Jacobian, I know that it will equal $1$, but I don't know what I'm taking partial derivatives of in the determinant. Can someone please help me with this integral?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87145/discussion-on-question-by-joseph-need-help-computing-the-double-integral-int).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost nailed it with your substitution $(x,y)\mapsto (u,v):=(x+y,y)$.  That said, you made a mistake when you thought that the region of integration is still $\mathbb{R}_{> 0}^2$.  The correct region is
$$\Omega:=\big\{(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}_{> 0}^2\,\big|\,u> v\big\}\,.$$
Hence,
$$I:=\int_0^\infty\,\int_0^\infty\,\frac{f(x+y)}{x+y}\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y=\iint_\Omega\,\frac{f(u)}{u}\,\text{d}u\,\text{d}v\,.$$
Assuming that $f$ is sufficiently nice so that Fubini's Theorem applies, we get
$$I=\int_0^\infty\,\int_0^u\,\frac{f(u)}{u}\,\text{d}v\,\text{d}u=\int_0^\infty\,u\,\left(\frac{f(u)}{u}\right)\,\text{d}u\,.$$
Thus,
$$I=\int_0^\infty\,f(u)\,\text{d}u=1\,.$$